# node -v 0.6.19. libxmljs. TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

Tags: node.js, freebsd, libxml2

On Ubuntu 11.10, with node 0.6.17, 0.6.18 and 0.6.19 with installed libxml2 (2.7.8) and libxml2-dev - everything was working properly.

On FreeBSD server with node 0.6.19, libxml2 version 20708 (xmllint --version; xmllint: using libxml version 20708) it gives the following error message:

```
/home/pathtofile/www/node_modules/libxmljs/lib/element.js:24
Element.prototype = bindings.Element.prototype;
                                   ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
   at Object. (/home/pathtofile/www/node_modules/libxmljs/lib/element.js:24:37)
   at Module._compile (module.js:446:26)
   at Object..js (module.js:464:10)
   at Module.load (module.js:353:31)
   at Function._load (module.js:311:12)
   at Module.require (module.js:359:17)
   at require (module.js:375:17)
   at Object. (/home/pathtofile/www/node_modules/libxmljs/lib/document.js:3:15)
   at Module._compile (module.js:446:26)
   at Object..js (module.js:464:10)
```

Comment: Have you tried node v0.6.19 on Ubuntu? Also what is the specific version of libxml2 on Ubuntu?

Comment: yes, I tried on Ubuntu and all work corret. On FreeBSD and Ubuntu I have libxml2 of same version: 2.7.8

Comment: What should I do to reproduce the error? Just `npm install libxmljs`?

Comment: yaup npm install libxmljs. Then in test file do 
var xml = require("libxml");

Comment: Are you aware that if you use `libxmljs` then you must also require it by calling `var xml = require("libxmljs")`? They are two different libraries.

Comment: yes sorry. I was mistake in my comment. I use require("libxmljs")

Comment: Forgot to ask: what is your specific FreeBSD server version/platform? FreeBSD/OpenBSD/NetBSD? 32-bit or 64-bit? It could be relevant.

Comment: I don't knwow. But I will know and will answer you

Comment: ok - fixed. Thanks everybody for help!

Comment: admins was remake libxml with additional headers and I was reinstall libxmljs module. And all works fine.

Comment: how can I close this question?

Comment: Usually you don't close questions, but choose a preferred answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add to your code before you call the xml objects:

`var xml = require("libxmljs")`